# Hiding output of function that calls system command

Tags: r, macos, function, ping, stderr

## Background

I'm looking at using [`pingr::ping`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pingr/versions/1.1.0/topics/ping) function on macOS to ping certain destinations. I want to hide [`pingr::ping`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pingr/versions/1.1.0/topics/ping) outputs in case of a malformatted destination.

### Notes

- The [`pingr::ping`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pingr/versions/1.1.0/topics/ping) actually makes use of [`pingr::ping_os`](https://github.com/r-lib/pingr/blob/master/R/ping-package.r) function to assemble command and [`system`](https://github.com/r-lib/pingr/blob/6da09409ba51a01bd16fdf782e06d74a9d32a469/R/ping-package.r#L65) command to execute ping. On macOS, malformatted destination returns in `ping` returning a message about wrongly formatted command. I want to hide that message from being printed to console.

## Example

```
hide_ping_output(destination = "www.google.com") -> a
hide_ping_output(destination = "wrong destination") -> b
```

### *Output to hide*

> ```
> usage: ping [-AaDdfnoQqRrv] [-c count] [-G sweepmaxsize]
>             [-g sweepminsize] [-h sweepincrsize] [-i wait]
>             [-l preload] [-M mask | time] [-m ttl] [-p pattern]
>             [-S src_addr] [-s packetsize] [-t timeout][-W waittime]
>             [-z tos] host
>        ping [-AaDdfLnoQqRrv] [-c count] [-I iface] [-i wait]
>             [-l preload] [-M mask | time] [-m ttl] [-p pattern] [-S src_addr]
>             [-s packetsize] [-T ttl] [-t timeout] [-W waittime]
>             [-z tos] mcast-group
> Apple specific options (to be specified before mcast-group or host like all options)
>             -b boundif           # bind the socket to the interface
>             -k traffic_class     # set traffic class socket option
>             -K net_service_type  # set traffic class socket options
>             -apple-connect       # call connect(2) in the socket
>             -apple-time          # display current time
> [1] NA NA NA
> ```

## Desired results

*No system output is printed in case of a malformatted destination.*

```
hide_ping_output(destination = "www.google.com")
hide_ping_output(destination = "wrong destination")
a; b
[1] 190.027  36.846  35.243
[1] NA NA NA
```

## Attempts

### `sink()`

```
hide_ping_output_sink <- function(...) {
     sink(tempfile())
     pingr::ping(...)
     sink(NULL)
}
hide_ping_output_sink(destination = "wrong destination") -> b
```

*Unwanted console output appears.*

> ```
> usage: ping [-AaDdfnoQqRrv] [-c count] [-G sweepmaxsize]
>             [-g sweepminsize] [-h sweepincrsize] [-i wait]
>             [-l preload] [-M mask | time] [-m ttl] [-p pattern]
>             [-S src_addr] [-s packetsize] [-t timeout][-W waittime]
>             [-z tos] host
>        ping [-AaDdfLnoQqRrv] [-c count] [-I iface] [-i wait]
>             [-l preload] [-M mask | time] [-m ttl] [-p pattern] [-S src_addr]
>             [-s packetsize] [-T ttl] [-t timeout] [-W waittime]
>             [-z tos] mcast-group
> Apple specific options (to be specified before mcast-group or host like all options)
>             -b boundif           # bind the socket to the interface
>             -k traffic_class     # set traffic class socket option
>             -K net_service_type  # set traffic class socket options
>             -apple-connect       # call connect(2) in the socket
>             -apple-time          # display current time
> ```

### `capture.output` / `invisible`

```
hide_ping_output_capture <- function(...) {
    capture.output(invisible(pingr::ping(...) ->> b))
    b
}
hide_ping_output_capture(destination = "wrong destination") -> b
```

*Unwanted console output appears.*

> ```
> >> hide_ping_output_capture(destination = "wrong destination") -> b
> usage: ping [-AaDdfnoQqRrv] [-c count] [-G sweepmaxsize]
>             [-g sweepminsize] [-h sweepincrsize] [-i wait]
>             [-l preload] [-M mask | time] [-m ttl] [-p pattern]
>             [-S src_addr] [-s packetsize] [-t timeout][-W waittime]
>             [-z tos] host
>        ping [-AaDdfLnoQqRrv] [-c count] [-I iface] [-i wait]
>             [-l preload] [-M mask | time] [-m ttl] [-p pattern] [-S src_addr]
>             [-s packetsize] [-T ttl] [-t timeout] [-W waittime]
>             [-z tos] mcast-group
> Apple specific options (to be specified before mcast-group or host like all options)
>             -b boundif           # bind the socket to the interface
>             -k traffic_class     # set traffic class socket option
>             -K net_service_type  # set traffic class socket options
>             -apple-connect       # call connect(2) in the socket
>             -apple-time          # display current time
> ```

Comment: Can you please fix the typo in `pingr`?

Comment: You should tag this with your OS. I don't see such output on Win10.

Comment: @Roland Of course, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a way to divert the system messages if they are created. They don't seem to come from R's message stream.

The best solution I can find is modifying `ping`:

```
hide_ping_output <- function(...) {
  f <- pingr::ping
  body(f)[[4]] <- quote(output <- suppressWarnings(system(os$cmd, 
                          intern = !verbose, ignore.stderr = TRUE)))
  f(...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for looking into this. I had the same problem, the pingr output appears to escape sink or capture.output.

Answer (score 1):

This may add to your problems but here's a way to sidestep the issue:

```
> library(iptools)
> library(pingr)

> hn <- "www.google.com"
> if (hostname_to_ip(hn) != "Not resolved") { ping(hn) }
[1] 617.094 610.771 610.603
> hn <- "foo bar"
> if (hostname_to_ip(hn) != "Not resolved") { ping(hn) }
>
```

`hostname_to_ip()` can take a long time to fail so maybe filter obvious bad hosts first.

Comment: Thanks for that's a partial solution. If nothing else appears I will accept. I was keen to learn more about `sink` and `capture.output` and see if someone could suggest solution that would actually capture *everything,* including any error messages ping may be returning. If nothing like that will appear, I will accept your solution.

Comment: Yeah - sorry!  I don't know enough about how those work. I went down the same path you did with (naturally) the same results.